# Output is coming different on localhost and when i run the file directly in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, localhost

I am working on this HTML template, so far everything is working fine, but when i open the application on localhost, some of the elements get messed up but fa-fa shows. Meanwhile when i directly open the index.html file all the elements are properly aligned but the fa-fa are not working properly.Below are the images of my application for reference.
[image: when i open the index.html file directly.]

[image: when i open the file through localhost]

Comment: Can you suggest the solution via looking at picture?

Comment: browser **developer** tools console - look for errors there - something isn't loading in each case

Comment: are you using any php files

Comment: I tried that. I am using  a single CSS file along with 4 javascript files, and all of them are loading in both the cases.

Comment: @JijoCleetus I am not using any php files right now, but i'll use it in the future.

Comment: clear your cache and cookies and recheck your localhost configuration.